# display json array object into html using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, json, object

Hi i am very new to JSON, i have the following JSON array object as a external filename.json, i want to read json data and display into the HTML page. Want to use jquery. Here is my external json. I have tried but no result

```
  [
   {
      "Order":"203",
      "HMC":"False",
      "Dataprovider":"Hatch",
      "Category":"Laptop",
      "Locale":"EN-US",
      "SKUID":"NX.VGTAA.003",
      "Brand":"Acer",
      "OS":"Windows 10 Pro",
      "SecureBio":null,
      "ProcessorNo":"i3",
      "VariationIds":[
         "57193947"
      ],
      "Sellerinfo":"sellers available",
      "DeviceName":"Acer TravelMate P2 (Intel)",
      "DeviceImage":{
         "AltText":"Acer TravelMate P2 (Intel)(10 Pro)",
         "ImageUrl":"http://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4E4RN?ver=faa3"
      },
      "Specification":{
         "OS":"OS: Windows 10 Pro",
         "ScreenSize":"Screen size: 14 inch",
         "Memory":"Memory: 4 GB",
         "Storage":"Storage: 500 GB",
         "BatteryLife":"Battery life: 8 hours",
         "CPU":"CPU: Intel® Core™ i3-8130U",
         "GPU":"",
         "StorageMedia":"",
         "FingerprintReader":"",
         "CPUFamily":"CPU family: Intel® Core™ i3-8xxx",
         "Touchscreen":"N"
      },
      "Feature":[
         "RemoteWork"
      ],
      "ShopNowCTA":{
         "Text":"Buy now",
         "Url":"",
         "Arialabel":"Buy the Acer TravelMate P2 (Intel)"
      },
      "LearnMoreCTA":{
         "Text":"",
         "Url":"",
         "Arialabel":""
      },
      "CompareCTA":{
         "Text":"COMPARE",
         "Url":"",
         "Arialabel":"Select Acer TravelMate P2410-G2-M-392D for comparison"
      },
      "HardCodedPrice":"699.99",
      "Modified":"2021-02-28T21:40:37.1602592",
      "ID":"95174733",
      "ProductID":"57193947",
      "Name":"P2410-G2-M-392D",
      "Series":"",
      "AdditionalCategories":[
         "Laptop"
      ],
      "OnMarket":"2018-06-02T00:00:00",
      "Retailers":[
         {
            "RetailerID":"90175",
            "RetailerName":"Acer Store",
            "PurchaseLink":"https://gethatch.com/iceleads_tracking/inbetween.xhtml?merch_id=90175&region=US&affiliate_id=53043&prod_id=1007548109&core_id=95174733",
            "PurchaseLinkDirect":"",
            "Logo":"https://gethatch.com/resources/images/merchant/mLogo90175.png",
            "Currency":"USD",
            "Price":"699.99",
            "StockInfo":"true",
            "StockCount":"1",
            "SourceDate":"2021-03-01T12:00:00",
            "BusinessID":"",
            "MarketFocus":"",
            "Group":""
         },
         {
            "RetailerID":"48915",
            "RetailerName":"Insight",
            "PurchaseLink":"https://gethatch.com/iceleads_tracking/inbetween.xhtml?merch_id=48915&region=US&affiliate_id=53043&prod_id=1109107689&core_id=95174733",
            "PurchaseLinkDirect":"",
            "Logo":"https://gethatch.com/resources/images/merchant/mLogo48915.png",
            "Currency":"USD",
            "Price":"646.99",
            "StockInfo":"false",
            "StockCount":"0",
            "SourceDate":"2021-03-01T12:00:00",
            "BusinessID":"",
            "MarketFocus":"",
            "Group":""
         }
      ],
      "OEMPromotions":"",
      "Colors":"",
      "Configuration":"4 GB | 500 GB | Intel® Core™ i3-8130U | ",
      "FamilyIDs":[
         "57193947"
      ],
      "FamilyConfig":[
         "57193947",
         "700",
         "OS: Windows 10 Pro | Screen size: 14 inch | Battery life: 8 hours | Memory: 4 GB | Storage: 500 GB | "
      ],
      "Show":"True",
      "FeaturePosition":"Laptop:99"
   },
   {
      "Order":"892",
      "HMC":"False",
      "Dataprovider":"Hatch",
      "Category":"Laptop",
      "Locale":"EN-US",
      "SKUID":"NX.VKLAA.001",
      "Brand":"Acer",
      "OS":"Windows 10 Pro",
      "SecureBio":null,
      "ProcessorNo":"i7",
      "VariationIds":[
         "71431281",
         "72606305",
         "79552705",
         "79552697"
      ],
      "Sellerinfo":"No sellers found",
      "DeviceName":"Acer TravelMate P6",
      "DeviceImage":{
         "AltText":"Acer TravelMate P6 (10 Pro)",
         "ImageUrl":"http://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4E4RX?ver=12a7"
      },
      "Specification":{
         "OS":"OS: Windows 10 Pro",
         "ScreenSize":"Screen size: 14 inch",
         "Memory":"Memory: 16 GB",
         "Storage":"Storage: 512 GB",
         "BatteryLife":"Battery life: 15 hours",
         "CPU":"CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-8565U",
         "GPU":"",
         "StorageMedia":"",
         "FingerprintReader":"",
         "CPUFamily":"CPU family: Intel® Core™ i7-8xxx",
         "Touchscreen":"Y"
      },
      "Feature":[
         "RemoteWork",
         "SecuredcorePC",
         "FaceLogin",
         "FingerprintLogin",
         "TouchScreen",
         "WindowsInk",
         "Connectivity"
      ],
      "ShopNowCTA":{
         "Text":"Buy now",
         "Url":"",
         "Arialabel":"Buy the Acer TravelMate P6"
      },
      "LearnMoreCTA":{
         "Text":"",
         "Url":"",
         "Arialabel":""
      },
      "CompareCTA":{
         "Text":"COMPARE",
         "Url":"",
         "Arialabel":"Select Acer TravelMate TMP614-51TG-792V for comparison"
      },
      "HardCodedPrice":"",
      "Modified":"2021-02-28T21:40:37.1602592",
      "ID":"97300307",
      "ProductID":"71431281",
      "Name":"TMP614-51TG-792V",
      "Series":"",
      "AdditionalCategories":[
         "Laptop"
      ],
      "OnMarket":"2019-07-20T00:00:00",
      "Retailers":[
         {
            "RetailerID":"48915",
            "RetailerName":"Insight",
            "PurchaseLink":"https://gethatch.com/iceleads_tracking/inbetween.xhtml?merch_id=48915&region=US&affiliate_id=53043&prod_id=1118626835&core_id=97300307",
            "PurchaseLinkDirect":"",
            "Logo":"https://gethatch.com/resources/images/merchant/mLogo48915.png",
            "Currency":"USD",
            "Price":"1490.99",
            "StockInfo":"false",
            "StockCount":"0",
            "SourceDate":"2021-03-01T12:00:00",
            "BusinessID":"",
            "MarketFocus":"",
            "Group":""
         }
      ],
      "OEMPromotions":"",
      "Colors":"",
      "Configuration":"16 GB | 512 GB | Intel® Core™ i7-8565U | ",
      "FamilyIDs":[
         "71431281"
      ],
      "FamilyConfig":[
         "",
         "",
         "OS: Windows 10 Pro | Screen size: 14 inch | Battery life: 15 hours | Memory: 16 GB | Storage: 512 GB | "
      ],
      "Show":"True",
      "FeaturePosition":"Laptop:99"
   }
   ]
```

I tried this code but no output

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title> jQuery getJSON() method </title>  
  
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/jsontohtml/devices.json',
   function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
      $('#results_div').append(
        '<li><label>Heading: ' + val.HMC  + '</label>' +
        '<span>Municipality Name: ' + val.Brand + '</span>' +
        '<small>Date: ' + val.Order + '</small></li>'
      );
    });
  });
}); 




</script>  
</head>  
  
<body>  
    <div id="results_div"></div>

  
</body>  
</html>
```

Let me know how to read the json data into html using jquery

Comment: Doesn't the code you provide already read the JSON array? What error do you get? Or what happens with your current code?

Comment: result i got empty screen, in the console shows the following errors "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: Does something change if you add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your head tag?

Comment: @MihailMinkov yes <meta charset="utf-8"> i tried but still no output only empty screen

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/jsontohtml/devices.json',
   function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('#results_div').append(
        '<li><label>Heading: ' + val.HMC  + '</label>' +
        '<span>Municipality Name: ' + val.Brand + '</span>' +
        '<small>Date: ' + val.Order + '</small></li>'
      );
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Update your script tag by this only one change you will need to pass data in each function

Comment: Hi still empty screen output, not getting any results from json to html.

Comment: I think you need to console the data variable first. By this, you will get the idea you are getting the valid array data or not